# Warning: mysqli::prepare() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in

Tags: php, sql, forms

I'm stuck here it's giving me this error =( any help?

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","odyssexxxxxx","xxxxxxxx")
or die ("Could not connect :" . mysql_error());

// db
mysql_select_db("odysseus_matchcode",$link);


// ejecucion del query

if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE members SET (nombre, apellido, username, email, password, salt, telefono) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) WHERE `cedula` = '$cedula'",$link)) {    
   $insert_stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $nombre, $apellido, $username, $email, $password, $random_salt, $telefono); 
    // Execute the prepared query.
   $insert_stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: You have used a mixture of `mysql` and `mysqli` functions.

Comment: What is `$mysqli` in your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing both your API and style.

`mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db` are of a different library than MySQLi.

Try having:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host","user","password","database");
```

Instead of:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","odyssexxxxxx","xxxxxxxx")
or die ("Could not connect :" . mysql_error());

// db
mysql_select_db("odysseus_matchcode",$link);
```

Then change your prepared statement to:

```
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE members SET (nombre, apellido, username, email, password, salt, telefono) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) WHERE `cedula` = ?")) { 

   $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $nombre, $apellido, $username, $email, $password, $random_salt, $telefono,$cedula);
```

I would also suggest reading the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Start at:

[Mysqli::Construct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) to see how to correctly initialize a MySQLi Class, then move on to prepared statements `stmt::FunctionName`

Comment: `'$cedula'` > SQL Injection.

Comment: @CORRUPT Thanks for pointing that out. The OP should have got an error for the prepared statement if strict reporting is turned on. But thanks